# How to set this type of texture in container flutter? Is it possible?

Tags: flutter, canvas

I want to add this type of texture to my container, Is it possible?

[image]

I tried this, but I didn't find any proper solution. I have one solution is that I use images, but I don't want to use images. Please provide me solution as I'm new to Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this like you can try to do it with texture widget

```
Container(
         width: 200,
         height: 200,
         child: Texture(textureId: textureId),
             )
```

but i think texture widget using is very hard for custom texture. I using image